# Angular Filter Shows Not Matched Values When Search On List Of Elements

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope, angular-filters

actually I have been trying to implement some custom drop-down search functionality in my application. And this drop-down contains a number of versions in this format. Please don't consider this question as duplicate as I asking this question after going through existing related solutions and no solution fix my issue. I big thanks in advance.

16.2(2)
16.2(1.11)
16.1(0)
12.7(3)M1
12.7(4)M1
12.7(5)M1
15.9(3)
15.7(3)M1
15.7(4)M1
15.7(5)M1

And the user can search for his required values using an input box to select. like

[image]

Now I am trying a search for values matched with 12 then as part of the response I am getting 16 matches values also but it should not happen as per my client requirement so only 12 matches related values should display. See these below images for unmatched responses with irrespective search values

[image]

[image]

And this is my codebase please 
script file :

```js
var appOne = angular.module('appOne', ['ngRoute']);
appOne.controller('controllerOne', function ($scope) {
    $scope.versionLi = [["217233", "16.2(2)", "0", "Class"], ["217220", "16.2(1.11)", "1", "Class"], ["212675", "16.1(0)", "2", "Class"], ["228973", "12.7(3)M1", "4", "Class"], ["228973", "12.7(4)M1", "4", "Class"], ["228973", "12.7(5)M1", "4", "Class"], ["231350", "15.9(3)", "3", "Class"], ["228973", "15.7(3)M1", "4", "Class"], ["228973", "15.7(4)M1", "4", "Class"], ["228973", "15.7(5)M1", "4", "Class"]];
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example - example-filter-filter-production</title>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myApp.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="appOne">
    <label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
    <table id="searchTextResults" ng-controller="controllerOne">
        <tr ng-repeat="friend in versionLi | filter : searchText ">
            <td>{{friend[1]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with you are trying to search in whole object of the array for the given index hence it returns the object for whatever the property matches the given search field.

For example when you search for 12 it also returns 16.1(0) as its object contains '12' in 0th index value -->  `["212675", "16.1(0)", "2", "Class"]` => "2**12**675"

As your intention is to display only the 1st elements of your given source array, I've put them in a separate array to make the filter work only on the required values like below.

```
$scope.toFilterList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.versionLi.length; i++) {
    var obj = $scope.versionLi[i];
    //console.log(obj[1]);
    $scope.toFilterList.push(obj[1]);
  }
```

Now we can simply apply search filter on the displayed values array.Please find the working demo below.

```js
var appOne = angular.module('appOne', ['ngRoute']);
appOne.controller('controllerOne', function($scope) {
  $scope.versionLi = [
    ["217233", "16.2(2)", "0", "Class"],
    ["217220", "16.2(1.11)", "1", "Class"],
    ["212675", "16.1(0)", "2", "Class"],
    ["228973", "12.7(3)M1", "4", "Class"],
    ["228973", "12.7(4)M1", "4", "Class"],
    ["228973", "12.7(5)M1", "4", "Class"],
    ["231350", "15.9(3)", "3", "Class"],
    ["228973", "15.7(3)M1", "4", "Class"],
    ["228973", "15.7(4)M1", "4", "Class"],
    ["228973", "15.7(5)M1", "4", "Class"]
  ];
  
  $scope.diffArray = [
    {"id":"217233", "value":"16.2(2)","index":"0", "type":"Class"},
    {"id":"217220", "value":"12.2(1.11)","index": "1","type":"Class"},
    {"id":"212675", "value":"16.9(0)","index": "2", "type":"Class"}
  ];
  
  $scope.toFilterList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.versionLi.length; i++) {
    var obj = $scope.versionLi[i];
    //console.log(obj[1]);
    $scope.toFilterList.push(obj[1]);
  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-filter-filter-production</title>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myApp.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="appOne">
  <label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
  <table id="searchTextResults" ng-controller="controllerOne">
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in toFilterList | filter : searchText ">
      <td>{{friend}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <label>Search 2 for key value object array <input ng-model="search.value"></label>
  <table id="searchTextResults" ng-controller="controllerOne">
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in diffArray | filter : search ">
      <td>{{obj.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Angular_10, Thanks for quick response its almost reach my requirement but I need that object also when I selecting values from dropdown that time I use to collect whole object(behind that value) not just single value. Any idea on this, please? I accespt your answer and voted too.

Comment: @Venki you might wanna put keys to your object array to attain full requirement like for both filtering and accessing object.Basically it should be key:value pair as of now your array is just values and index as keys which makes it hard to filter or maintain.

Comment: can you please give suggest me that response data structure then I will incorporate with backend team to get such a format data to my angular app.

Comment: try assigning some keys to the object array like $scope.versionLi = [
    {"id":"217233", "value":"16.2(2)","index":"0", "type":"Class"},
    {"id":"217220", "value":"16.2(1.11)","index": "1","type":"Class"},
    {"id":"212675", "value":"16.1(0)","index": "2", "type":"Class"}
  ]; based on your feasibility.

Comment: Please look at the updated answer on how to achieve both filtering and entire object with key value object array.Hope this helps

Comment: yes even after changing list structure in key and value pair still issue persist. I have tried with this response structure - https://justpaste.it/1fbs0

Comment: What issue persists ? Can you use like mentione in answer for this kind of array.You don't need to run a js loop and create new list when you have key value array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162589/discussion-between-venki-and-angular-10).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Angular_10 to suppose the very close answer to my requirement and as we did discuss on personal chatroom on this like even we change response structure with key and value format if even any dropdown value having search value as a part it then those values also showing as part of that search filter. So, after spending some time on stackoverflow I got a fix for what I am exactly looking for

This code snippet -

```js
var appOne = angular.module('appOne', ['ngRoute']);
appOne.controller('controllerOne', function($scope) {
  $scope.versionLi = [
    ["217233", "16.2(2)", "0", "Class"],
    ["217220", "16.2(1.11)", "1", "Class"],
    ["212675", "16.1(0)", "2", "Class"],
    ["228973", "12.7(3)M1", "4", "Class"],
    ["228973", "12.7(4)M1", "4", "Class"],
    ["228973", "12.7(5)M1", "4", "Class"],
    ["231350", "15.9(3)", "3", "Class"],
    ["228973", "15.7(3)M1", "4", "Class"],
    ["228973", "15.7(4)M1", "4", "Class"],
    ["228973", "15.7(5)M1", "4", "Class"]
  ];
  
  
  $scope.startsWith = function (actual, expected) {
  var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
  return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
 }
  
  $scope.diffArray = [
    {"id":"217233", "value":"16.12(2)","index":"0", "type":"Class"},
    {"id":"217220", "value":"12.2(1.11)","index": "1","type":"Class"},
    {"id":"212675", "value":"16.9(0)","index": "2", "type":"Class"}
  ];
  
  $scope.toFilterList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.versionLi.length; i++) {
    var obj = $scope.versionLi[i];
    //console.log(obj[1]);
    $scope.toFilterList.push(obj[1]);
  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-filter-filter-production</title>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myApp.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="appOne">
  <label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
  <table id="searchTextResults" ng-controller="controllerOne">
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in toFilterList | filter : searchText ">
      <td>{{friend}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <label>Search 2 for key value object array <input ng-model="search.value"></label>
  <table id="searchTextResults" ng-controller="controllerOne">
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in diffArray | filter : search:startsWith ">
      <td>{{obj.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```